# Auto set owner to entity - API Platform

Tags: symfony, events, api-platform.com

Good evening, everyone,
I use API Platform, and I would like to automatically add the owner to my entities when they are created.
I created an Event, to override API Platform, which takes the current user and adds it.
But my Event never goes off, yet it does exist in debug:event-dispatcher

```
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\EventPriorities;
use App\Entity\MediaObject;
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

final class AddOwnerToEntity implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    /**
     * @var TokenStorageInterface
     */
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage) {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return [
            KernelEvents::VIEW => ['attachOwner', EventPriorities::PRE_WRITE],
        ];
    }

    public function attachOwner(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event) {
        $entity = $event->getControllerResult();
        $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();

        if (!$entity instanceof MediaObject || Request::METHOD_POST !== $method) {
            // Only handle Article entities (Event is called on any Api entity)
            return;
        }

        // maybe these extra null checks are not even needed
        $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();
        if (!$token) {
            return;
        }

        $owner = $token->getUser();
        if (!$owner instanceof User) {
            return;
        }

        $entity->setOwner($owner);
    }
}
```

I get a database insert error, telling me that user is null. If in the attachOwner() function I do a var_dump or an exit, nothing changes.
Do you have any ideas?
Thank you very much,
Guillaume

**EDIT**
My mystake, the code works for objects managed by the API Platform core, but not for the upload system described here: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/file-upload/#handling-file-upload-1
It was simply necessary to add the following line:

```
public function __invoke(Request $request): MediaObject {
    [...]
    $mediaObject->setOwner($this->getUser());

    [...]
}
```

If it helps....
Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to persist and flush the entity. Use dependency injection to insert the EntityManagerInterface $em and persist+flush the entity at the end of the method.

Comment: Thanks T. van den Berg, but it's my mistake, I edit my previous answer.